# Google Earth pro license

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Google Earth Pro is now free, according to [this](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/tech/news/a625719/google-earth-pro-is-now-free-to-download-with-licence-key-signup.html#~p58F80FZPeB30z).

How do I obtain this license key?

Comment: why do you vote for this to be closed. IMHO it is a reasonable question and Google did not answer the question.

Comment: Really, folks, Google made it very difficult for me to find out how to get the 'FREAKIN' key.  I read all of their documentation that led me in a continuous circle.  About the time I got PO'd, I turned to Stack Overflow.  Thanks to csetzkom's question, I now have a clue.

Comment: You are welcome - still not sure why so many people voted to close this etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can just download is [here.](https://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/desktop.html)  If you do not have a key, use your email address and the key **GEPFREE** to sign in.  You can find complete instructions [here.](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/176160?hl=en)